# Attempting to display array in a table (Javascript + html)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

Currently, I have a text box and date-time local input that stores something into an array every time I click on a submit button. The arrays work, however, I do not seem to be able to put them into a table using a for loop and displaying them. Here is the JavaScript that is relevant:

```
var eventName = new Array();
var theDate = new Array();
var index = 0;
var index2 = 0;

function submitNewEvent() {

eventName[index] = document.getElementById("eventName").value;
index++;

theDate[index2] = document.getElementById("date").value;
index2++;



    var newTable = "<table>";
    for (var i=0; i < eventName.length; i++){
    newTable += "" + eventName[i] + "<br>"
    }
}
```

Here is how I am attempting to display the table in HTML:

```
    <script> 
        document.write ('<p>colour1: ' + newTable + '</p>');
    </script>
```

Any help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *`java`*? please make sure to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

Comment: I have some questions for you, how and where do you invoke `submitNewEvent()`? Where do you close your `</table>`? - Where are your `<tr>` elements? - Where are your `<td>` elements? - Do you know what are all the necessary elements to properly build a *table*? - What are all the elements you can use in a table?

Comment: Additionally,  `var eventName = [];` is used for brevity. - Instead of the indexes variables you can simply use `Array.push()` like `eventName.push("blah")` - `document.write` is often referred as the JavaScript's *bad* parts (for often good reasons) and should be replaced with other methods.

Comment: Also, where do you use your `theDate` array?

Answer (score 2):

You could use only one array `events = [];`
Inside that array you can append using `.push()`  Object literals that will look like:

```
[
    {
       name : "Super event!",
       date : "12/31/2017"
    },
    {
       name : "This is some event name",
       date : "09/22/2017"
    }
]
```

Here's an example:

```js
// Cache your selectors

var EL_name = document.getElementById("name"),
    EL_date = document.getElementById("date"),
    EL_table = document.getElementById("table"), // Our empty table in HTML
    events = [];                        // One simple array to store object literals


function submitNewEvent() {

  // Create an Object literal with out event dara
  var eventObj = {
    name : EL_name.value,
    date : EL_date.value
  };
  
  // Create Row
  var row = `<tr>
               <td>${eventObj.name}</td>
               <td>${eventObj.date}</td>
             </tr>`;
  
  // Clear inputs
  EL_name.value = EL_date.value = "";
  
  // Store into Array
  events.push( eventObj );
  
  // Insert row into table
  EL_table.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", row);

}
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
th, td {border: 1px solid #aaa; padding: 4px 8px;}
```

```html
Name<input type="text" id="name">
Date<input type="text" id="date">
<button onclick="submitNewEvent()">ADD EVENT</button>

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>DATE</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- JS will insert here new TR -->
</table>
```

Although only the last event `<tr>` HTML is added to the `<table>` all the `events` array with all the entered events is successfully preserved and can be reused or submitted to a server database!

Comment: thanks so much! can you help me store these into local storage and then bringing it up on another page?

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` is a bad practice. Avoid it.

If you want to build a table in Vanilla JS, you should follow this model:

*(For the sake of simplicity, we build only one column in the example...)*

```js
var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
    table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
    tr = null,
    td = null,
    txt = '';

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
  td = document.createElement('td');
  tr = document.createElement('tr');
  
  td.appendChild(txt);
  tr.appendChild(td);
  table.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr, th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}


th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Test</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see you closing the table at the end nor using `<tr> and <td>`. Read this and give it a shot : [HTML Tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)
I guess you could try something like this:

```js
var newTable = "<table><tr><td>";
    for (var i=0; i < eventName.length; i++){
    newTable += "" + eventName[i] + "<br>"
    }
newTable += "</td></tr></table>";
```

This could do the trick. LMK if it helped u out.